# Error: "patch does not apply" when editing a hung in patch mode

Tags: git, addition, edit, patch, interactive

I want to interactively add this hung by editing it:

```
@@ -55,3 +50,28 @@
   {
-    if(n_arguments == 1)
+    inputed_command = get_line(); //gets the user's input line from the stdin.
+
+    //we edit the user's input as needed according to qtp rules.
+    /*STRING EDITING FUNCTIONS*/
+    replace_string_chars(inputed_command, 9, ' ');
+    remove_char(inputed_command, 13);
+    remove_comments(inputed_command);
+    remove_extra_spaces(inputed_command);
+    uncapitalize(inputed_command);
+    /*END OF STRING EDITING FUNCTIONS*/
+
+    //the command gets seperated from the user's input ex. playmove w c3, here the command is playmove.
+    command = command_decode(inputed_command);
+    //the arguments are seperated from the user's input in an 2D array ex. playmove w c3, here the arguments are w and c3.
+    arguments = arguments_decode(inputed_command, &n_arguments);
+
+    //the user specified command is executed by matching the user's command with the engine's available commands. if the user's command is not one of the engine's known commands then a descriptive error is printed.
+    if(strcmp(command, "name") == 0)
+      name();
+    else if(strcmp(command, "known_command") == 0)
+      known_command(arguments, n_arguments);
+    else if(strcmp(command, "list_commands") == 0)
+      list_commands();
+    else if(strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
+      quit(&quit_game);
+    else if(strcmp(command, "boardsize") == 0)
     {
```

I would like to stage this part only:

```
@@ -55,3 +50,28 @@
   {
-    if(n_arguments == 1)
+    inputed_command = get_line(); //gets the user's input line from the stdin.
+
+    //we edit the user's input as needed according to qtp rules.
+    /*STRING EDITING FUNCTIONS*/
+    replace_string_chars(inputed_command, 9, ' ');
+    remove_char(inputed_command, 13);
+    remove_comments(inputed_command);
+    remove_extra_spaces(inputed_command);
+    uncapitalize(inputed_command);
+    /*END OF STRING EDITING FUNCTIONS*/
+
+    //the command gets seperated from the user's input ex. playmove w c3, here the command is playmove.
+    command = command_decode(inputed_command);
+    //the arguments are seperated from the user's input in an 2D array ex. playmove w c3, here the arguments are w and c3.
+    arguments = arguments_decode(inputed_command, &n_arguments);
+
     {
```

but when i save & exit this error occurs "patch does not apply".

I've read that i need to edit the numbers between the @@ characters but i never get it right. Please be descriptive about how to solve this error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple case of just removing '+' lines from the patch. The only thing I see that could be causing your patch to fail is that the last curly brace is indented differently in your two hunks.

Is your editor applying auto-formatting rules while you edit the patch?

Comment: I removed the unwanted added lines and the curly brace that was out of place and still got the same error. No, I don't think that my editor is applying auto-formatting rules.

Comment: @PlatwnAce That looks like it to me also.  The brace indentation looks wrong in the original. (If that's just an artifact of how this was posted to StackOverflow, please fix it.  Character-for-character exactness is important in this type of question.)

Comment: @Kaz Yes it was an artifact. Sorry for the confusion. It's fixed now.

Comment: @PlatwnAce How about expanding spaces to tabs or such?  If you're doing `git add --patch`, you should be able to just delete `+` lines when editing a hunk. In fact you can add `+` lines too. (These won't go to your working copy; they are in the staged index only.)

Comment: When I just delete the  + lines I get the error. The fact that there are spaces instead of tabs does not affect the outcome.

Comment: Yes, spaces versus tabs in the `+` area won't affect the outcome. If they are in context lines, they will (there is no patch "fuzz" allowed here, I don't think).  (Ditto in any `-` lines that are converted to context lines by replacing `-` with space).